# Swift 4 Dictionary [String : AnyObject] sort by key in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary defined as [String: AnyObject] like so:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
```

Now I am trying to put them into alphabetical order by key. I have tried the following:

```
self.appDelegate.communityArray = json.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: AnyObject)]' to
>   type '[String : AnyObject]?'

What am I doing wrong?

My variable json is:

```
({"BBB" : Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")}, {"AAA" : Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")})
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
({"AAA" : Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")}, {"BBB" : Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")})
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. The result of the sort function is an array of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first step is to change

`let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]`

to

`let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : Any]`

But I cannot understand why you want to sort a Dictionary.. Maybe You intended to declare variable json as Array?

Answer (score 1):

Your `communityArray` is the wrong type. As the error notes, the type you need is `[(key: String, value: AnyObject)]` (an array of tuples).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your actual JSON I will have to guess a little. But as others have told you, you should not rely on the order of keys in a `Dictionary`. You can always sort *just* the keys and access your `Dictionary` accordingly. Since `sorted` will return an `Array` the following Playground should show you the effects:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
    {"BBB" : ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], "AAA" : ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : Any]
    print(dict)
    let array = dict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
    print(array)
    print(type(of:array))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I would suggest you amend your structure definition in order to make some line like

```
let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Any].self, from:jsonData)
```

work inside your `do`. This line will not work since `Any` cannot implement `Codable` so it should be replaced by the "real thing". The current version will give you `NSArray` objects as values in your `dict` which are a pain to work with. Your code will benefit greatly from a proper definition (if possible).